# Cannot bind widget to a method in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def hover_in(self, num):
        i = 20
        print(num+i)


    def create():
        Player.button = Button(text="Hover")
        Player.button.grid()
        i=10
        Player.button.bind("<Enter>", lambda num=i: Player.hover_in(num))

p1 = Player
p1.create()
```

Every time I hover over the button, it comes up with `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Event' and 'int'`.

I then change `Player.hover_in(num)` to `Player.hover_in(self, num)`, but then I get `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

I then change `def create()` to `def create(self)`, to get `TypeError: create() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` and the button doesn't generate at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your goal? Is it to increment `i` every time the user hovers over the button? Are you expecting to have a single `i` for each separate button, or a single `i` that is common to all instances of `Player`?

Comment: I just want to be able to add the two numbers "num" and "i". This was taken from a code for a Battleships game. I created a 10*10 grid, and I intend to change the colour of the button when I hover over it. It was working fine, until I started using classes, which I am new to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every time I hover over the button, it comes up with TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Event' and 'int'

That is because tkinter will pass along an object representing the event to the called function. You define the bound function as `lambda num=i: Player.hover_in(num)`, so when the event gets called, `num` is set to the event object.

The quick fix is to make sure your lambda function accepts the event parameter with something like this:

```
lambda event, num=i: Player.hover_in(num)
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed

Answer (score -1):

You have to convert self and i to string by the str() method

**Working code:**

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def hover_in(self):
        i = 20
        print(str(self)+str(i))


    def create():
        Player.button = Button(text="Hover")
        Player.button.grid()
        i=10
        Player.button.bind("<Enter>", lambda num=i: Player.hover_in(num))

p1 = Player
p1.create()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am afraid this does not work. I want to add num, which is 10, to i in hover_in(), which is 20. Using your code outputs "<Enter event state=Mod1 focus=False x=41 y=23>20" because you are converting "self" to string in hover_in(self), but have left out "num".

Comment: This makes the exact same mistake as the code in the question. `num` is being set to the event object.